# Service Fabric Actor method call does not return value

Tags: c#, azure, return-value, actor, azure-service-fabric

I have a simple C# console application that interacts with a Service Fabric actor and receives info via actor events.

The problem is that I call an actor method on client EventHandler that returns an `int[]` value and even though the method is executed correctly on actor (ActorEventSource messages debugging), client does not receive return value an exits method without any error exception.

This is a scheme of the client

```
    class LobbyEventsHandler : IGameLobbyEvents
    {
        private GameManager p_gameManager;

        public LobbyEventsHandler(GameManager i_gameManager)
        {
            p_gameManager = i_gameManager;
        }

        public void GameStart()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Game starting");
            p_gameManager.StartGame();
        }
    }

    class GameManager
    {
        public int state;
        private int[] p_playerPosReal;
        private IGameManagerActor p_actor;
        public string playerName;

        public IGameManagerActor actor
        {
            set
            {
                p_actor = value;
            }
        }

        public GameManager()
        {
            state = 1;
        }

        public void SubscribeToLobbyEvents()
        {
            p_actor.SubscribeAsync<IGameLobbyEvents>(new LobbyEventsHandler(this));
        }

        public void StartGame()
        {
            state = 2;
            Console.WriteLine("Getting position");
            p_playerPosReal = p_actor.GetPlayerPos(playerName).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Position gotten");
        }
    }

   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool exit = false;
            GameManager gameManager = new GameManager();
            while (!exit)
            {
                gameManager.actor = ActorProxy.Create<IGameManagerActor>(new ActorId("Manager"), APP_NAME);
                gameManager.SubscribeToLobbyEvents();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

The method `GetPlayerPos` must return a `Task<int[]>` value but it isnt working, actor finish his execution and client doesn't catch it

What should I do?

Comment: Shouldn't you show `GetPlayerPos` code instead of this snippet? It looks like a reason of failure lies there.

Comment: `GetPlayerPos` is a simple method. It returns the value of an `Dictionary<string,int[]>`

Comment: This happens with every actor method that returns a value, not with method that only return `Task`.
If this method is called on the Main method body it works correctly.